# Confusion passing string as an argument to C function

Tags: c

```
void convert(char *str){
  int i = 0;
  while (str[i]){
    if (isupper(str[i])){
      tolower(str[i]);
    }
    else if (islower(str[i])){
      toupper(str[i]);
    }
    i++;
  }
  printf(str);
}
```

In the function, I tried to reverse the case of each of the letters in a string. I called the function like this:

```
convert(input);
```

Where input is a type of char *. I got a segmentation fault error. What's wrong here?

Thank you!

**UPDATE:**
My input is taken from argv[1].

```
  char *input;
  if (argc !=2){/* argc should be 2 for correct execution */
    /* We print argv[0] assuming it is the program name */
    printf("Please provide the string for conversion \n");
    exit(-1);
  }
  input = argv[1];
```

Comment: What is the *value* of `input`? Note that just calling `tolower` doesn't actually change the value - it *returns* the lower case value... you'd need to write it back into the `char *`.

Comment: Is `input` null-terminated? Segmentation Fault probably is caused by that you are trying to access a memory location outside the allocated area. Also, an easier way to change the casing is to apply modulus: `str[i] = str[i] % 0x20;`

Comment: How is `input` initialized?

Comment: You can't just assume that the `argv[0]` is a writable string, copy it somewhere before fooling around with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason this does not work is that you are dropping the results of `toupper` and `tolower`. You need to assign the results back to the string passed into your function:

```
if (isupper(str[i])){
    str[i] = tolower(str[i]);
} else if (islower(str[i])){
    str[i] = toupper(str[i]);
}
```

Note that in order for this to work the `str` must be *modifiable*, meaning that a call `convert("Hello, World!")` would be undefined behavior.

```
char str[] = "Hello, World!";
convert(str);
printf("%s\n", str);
```